# Groovy UTC date formatting

Tags: javascript, datetime, groovy, datetime-format, java-time

Okay, so I'm doing a simple UTC date formatting script which takes UTC and converts it in to a specific format for date and time. I can get the script to work fine in javascript, but the plugin I'm using requires Groovy apparently. I'm not familiar with it, I've been told that the programming is essentially the same as it can use javascript libraries/language. In any case, here is my code snippet:

```
import java.util.*;

var d = new Date();
var CurrentDay = ('0' + d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);
var CurrentMonth = ('0' + d.getUTCMonth()).slice(-2);
var CurrentYear = d.getUTCFullYear();
var CurrentHours = ('0' + d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2);
var CurrentMinutes = ('0' + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2);
var CurrentSeconds = ('0' + d.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);
var DateFormatted = CurrentYear.toString() + CurrentMonth.toString() + CurrentDay.toString() + CurrentHours.toString() + CurrentMinutes.toString() + CurrentSeconds.toString();
return DateFormatted;
```

I'm getting this error message back when I attempt to run my script:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.var() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.Date) values: [Thu Jun 06 21:18:43 CDT 2013]
Possible solutions: wait(), run(), run(), every(), any(), wait(long)
Parameters:
{}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Also, I can get this script to run exactly as I would like as a normal javascript.

Comment: BTW, UTC isn't a format, it's a time zone. :-) Though if you add "Z" to the end of your string (e.g. 20130607142105Z) you'd have an ISO8601 format date and time string.

Comment: Whoever told you Groovy and Javascript have the same syntax is wrong...  It's 95% compatible with JAVA, not Javascript.

Comment: Why the JavaScript tag? Are you aware that JavaScript has *nothing* to do with Java?  http://javascriptisnotjava.io/

Comment: I had already accepted an Answer on this question more than four years ago. thanks for the input.

Comment: A lot has changed in four years regarding date-time work on the Java platform.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The equivalent of `var` from JavaScript is ["def"](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22) in Groovy. Moreover, setting up a date format is easier in Groovy using [Groovy Date](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html):

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
def now = new Date()
println now
println now.format("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")


//Prints:
Fri Jun 07 02:57:58 UTC 2013
06/07/2013T02:57:58.737Z
```

You can modify the format according to your need. For available formats refer [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: This one gets the date fields out of order.  Try yyyy-MM-dd instead of MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: The `X` placeholder should be preferred over the literal `'Z'` in the format string if using Java7+

Comment: FYI, these troublesome old date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: @Andrew how does the comment result in a downvote? Is anything wrong with the answer?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.  As noted with at least one other person, the 'Z' part should not be used.  X should be used.

Comment: link for Groovy Date is broken, can one fix it please?

Answer (score 9):

## tl;dr

Java syntax here, but you can call java.time classes in Groovy too.

```
Instant.now()
       .toString()
```

> 2017-01-23T01:23:45.654321Z

## Avoid legacy classes

The Question and other Answers use troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Using java.time

Apparently you want to generate a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format representing a date-time value in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone.

The [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

The java.time classes use ISO 8691 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2017-01-23T01:23:45.987654321Z

If you want whole seconds, without a fraction, [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

Comment: Great hint.
Would be perfect to update example with full package name of the Java Instance class: java.time.Instant

Comment: @SergeyShcherbakov Done.

Answer (score 4):

You should generally never change the default time zone just for your local benefits, as that affects all the code in JVM - it may want the actual local time zone to be the default, for example. Hence, using TimeZone.setDefault() is a bad practice unless you are sure that all your code will want that time zone and that all code is yours and that this will never change. That is a lot to ask.

Instead you should explicitly specify the time zone of interest in your calls.

- If you want to use a date/time format that is specific to the locale of the user/machine, you should use the [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) factory, specifically one of the following static methods - they will take care of complex locale/language specifics not possible using any other approach (including SimpleDateFormatter):
- [getDateTimeInstance() - for the default locale and default styles.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance())
- [getDateTimeInstance(int dateStyle, int timeStyle)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance(int,%20int)) for the default locale and specified styles
- [getDateTimeInstance(int dateStyle, int timeStyle, Locale locale)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance(int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale)) for specified styles and locale

Once you get that DateFormatter instance you will want to call the [setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)) on it. That will make that formatter use that time zone. You can also use any other time zone.

Finally, you will call the [dateFormat.format(Date date)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) method to get a String representation of that date, in the locale, style and time zone of choice.

If you do NOT want locale specific format but want to fix to something of your own, such as ISO, instead of creating the DateFormat instance using a static factory method described above, you will want to use the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead. Specifically you will use the [new SimpleDateFormat(String pattern)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String)) constructor. The pattern would be following the definitions in the SimpleDateFormat JavaDoc, and could be 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS', for example.

You would then call the setTimeZone() method on that SimpleDateFormat instance the same was as for (any) DateFormat. In Groovy you can skip the explicit SimpleDateFormat creation and you can instead use the Groovy Date enhancement, its [format(String format, TimeZone tz)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.util.TimeZone)) method - it will do the SimpleDateFormat stuff under the covers.

Locale-specific format approach example (Java and/or Groovy):

```
String gimmeUTC(Date date, Locale locale) {
  DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);
  dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Fixed format approach example (Java and/or Groovy):

```
String gimmeUTC(Date date, Locale locale) {
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
  dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Fixed format example (Groovy only):

```
String gimmeUTC(Date date) {
  return date.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS', TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'));
}
```

Comment: FYI, these troublesome old date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: Yes, that is very true. But this is a legacy question, specific to a legacy class and those classes are still widely used (esp. when there is no choice due to other libraries used). they are often used incorrectly. Hence I felt compelled to answer it in that domain.